# Std iterator assignment error

Tags: c++, iterator, find, std

Please bear with me if the question is silly.

The following are defined in a header file :

```
typedef char NAME_T[40];

struct NAME_MAPPING_T
{
    NAME_T englishName;
    NAME_T frenchName;
};

typedef std::vector<NAME_MAPPING_T> NAMES_DATABASE_T;
```

Later the need comes that a particular english name be found :

```
const NAMES_DATABASE_T *wordsDb;

string str;

std::find_if(   wordsDb->begin(), 
                wordsDb->end(), 
                [str](const NAME_MAPPING_T &m) -> bool { return strncmp(m.englishName, str.c_str(), sizeof(m.englishName)) == 0; } );
```

This code (which I copy-pasted to be honest) compiles, but if I want to check the value returned by find_if(), like this :

```
NAMES_DATABASE_T::iterator it;
it = std::find_if(blah ..)
```

**the code will NOT compile !**

In effect the line 
**it = std::find_if(...)** 
will return the error :

```
error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

What is wrong ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is there a reason in using char arrays for the names instead of std::string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`const NAMES_DATABASE_T *wordsDb;`

Your `wordsDb` is const, therefore `wordsDb->begin()` returns a const iterator, therefore `find_if` returns a const iterator as well. You're trying to assign that const iterator to the non-const `NAMES_DATABASE_T::iterator it`, hence the error.

You can use `NAMES_DATABASE_T::const_iterator` to get a const iterator. And you should use `std::string` instead of those char buffers, unless there are some rare circumstances that require otherwise.